# Uniformly mix n and m flags

Tags: algorithm

I need to "uniformly" mix `n` ones and `m` zeros, always starting from `1`. If solution is not unique, any one of the best solutions is sufficient.

E.g.:

- `n=2, m=2`: 1,0,1,0
- `n=2, m=5`: 1001000 or 1000100
- `n=5, m=2`: 1101101 or 1011011 or 1101011

Cannot come up with a simple and short solution (C++ preferable).

By uniform, I mean that minimum and maximum counts of consecutive zeros in the solution should be equal or differ by 1.

And same for minimum and maximum counts of consecutive ones.

**Update**

`1,0,1,0` and `1,1,0,0` both satisfy uniformity requirements, but the former is "better mixed".

I think another requirement ("best mix") should be as follows:

Out of two solutions, the one that has smaller max count of consecutive 0s and smaller max count of consecutive 1s is better.

If a solution has smaller max count of consecutive 0s but larger max count of consecutive 1s, then it is an equally good solution (I am not sure if this case is even possible).

Comment: How do you define *"uniformly"*?

Comment: @PM77-1 See updated post

Comment: @teapot418 Yes, I need a better definition of uniform. Should include "best mixing" property. `1,0,1,0` is "better mixed" than `1,1,0,0`. Don't know how to define "best mixing" formally. Help appreciated.

Comment: minimize (as small as possible) the maximum consecutive digit lengths?

Comment: @teapot418 Maybe. Out of two solutions, the one that has smaller max count of consecutive 0s and  smaller max count of consecutive 1s is better. If a solution has smaller max count of consecutive 0s but larger max count of consecutive 1s, then it is an equally good solution (I am not sure if this case is even possible).

Comment: (Theorizing) The digit with the smaller (or equal) count will have runs of length 1. Assuming `m>n`, runs of the other digit will be `m/n` long and `m%n` of them will be one longer. Does that sound right? Now just to code that...

Comment: @teapot418 I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the code below based on [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77496944/2052436) proposed by @teapot418.

It may produce slightly different results from @teapot418 code.

```
His : 111011101110110110110110
Mine: 111011011011011011011011
```

Both results satisfy requirements, but I feel that mine is slightly "better mixed". I guess "best mix" definition needs to be refined.

```
std::vector<int> mix (int n1, int n0)
{
    if (!n1)
        return std::vector<int>(n0, 0);
    if (!n0)
        return std::vector<int>(n1, 1);

    std::vector<int> res;
    res.reserve(n1 + n0);

    if (n1 >= n0) {
        int q = n1 / (n0 + 1);
        int r = n1 % (n0 + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= n0; ++i, --r) {
            for (int j = 0; j < q + (r > 0); ++j)
                res.push_back(1);
            if (i < n0)
                res.push_back(0);
        }
    } else {
        int q = n0 / n1;
        int r = n0 % n1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i, --r) {
            res.push_back(1);
            for (int j = 0; j < q + (r > 0); ++j)
                res.push_back(0);
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm like Bresenham's line drawing.
Y-step corresponds to "1", X-step corresponds to "0".

`state` stuff and the second for-loop are intended to cyclic shift the
result to provide  `always starting from 1` (shift it to the first one after zeros)

https://onlinegdb.com/j4CazsBtg

```
void Distribute(int ones, int zeros) {
    int n = ones + zeros;
    int cnt = 0;
    int state = 0;
    int* res = new int[n];
    int err = n / 2;
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        err = err - ones;
        if (err < 0) {
            res[i] = 1;
            err += n;
            if (state==1) {
               state = 2;
               cnt = i;
            }
        }
        else {
           res[i] = 0;
           if (state == 0) state = 1;
        }

    }
    for (int i=cnt; i < n; i++) 
       printf("%d",res[i]);
    for (int i=0; i < cnt; i++) 
       printf("%d",res[i]);
    printf("\n");
    delete [] res;
}  

int main()
{
    Distribute(24, 0);
    Distribute(20, 4);
    Distribute(17, 7);
    Distribute(16, 8);
    Distribute(11, 13);
    Distribute(5, 19);
    Distribute(2, 22);
    Distribute(1, 23);
    return 0;
}

111111111111111111111111
111110111110111110111110
111011011011101101110110
110110110110110110110110
101010101001010101010100
100001000010001000010000
100000000000100000000000
100000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Yes, `110110110110111011011011` is better than `101110110110111011011101` according to the **update**. But it's a good start for me, thank you @MBo.

Comment: OK, I see. I'll think how to correct the code (cyclic shift works for some examples, but logic is too complex)

Comment: Modified code..

Answer (score 2):

Theory: the digit with the smaller (or equal) count will have runs of length 1. Assuming `m>n`, runs of the other digit will be `m/n` long and `m%n` of them will be one longer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int digit, int count) {
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        printf("%d", digit);
}

void Distribute(int m, int n) {
    if (n==0) return;
    if (m==0) { // let's get the division by zero case out of the way
        print(1, n);
        return;
    }
    int runs[2];
    int bonus[2];
    if (m>n) {
        runs[0] = m/n;
        bonus[0] = m%n;
        runs[1] = 1;
        bonus[1] = 0;
    } else {
        runs[0] = 1;
        bonus[0] = 0;
        runs[1] = n/m;
        bonus[1] = n%m;
    }
    int digit = 1;
    int counter[2] = {m, n};
    while (counter[0]+counter[1]>0) {
        print(digit, runs[digit]);
        counter[digit] -= runs[digit];
        if (bonus[digit]) {
            print(digit, 1);
            counter[digit]--;
            bonus[digit]--;
        }
        digit = !digit;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Distribute(7,17);
    puts("");
    Distribute(13,11);
    puts("");
    Distribute(19,5);   
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs

```
111011101110110110110110
100100101010101010101010
100001000010000100001000
```

Comment: Yes, this approach works. Note we have to adapt starting point too. And there is a kind of non-uniformity - for example, left part of result contains only length 3 series, right part of result contains only length 2 series (perhaps it is not important for author)

Comment: @MBo I'm counting on the "If solution is not unique, any one of the best solutions is sufficient." bit

Comment: That's interesting. Can you give a source tor your first sentence?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the "runs of length 1" one? If n=m, the solution is just alternating digits. If ones>zeros and zeros have at least one run of length two or more, you can get a better solution by breaking up that run and stuffing a zero between some ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another application of @teapot418's observation that the character (`0` or `1`) that appears less often always appears as a string comprised of a single character. This time it's in Ruby.

```
def doit(n1, n0)
  if n1 <= n0
    helper(n1, '1', n0, '0')
  else
    helper(n0, '0', n1, '1')
  end
end
```

```
def helper(nbr_smaller, char_smaller, nbr_larger, char_larger)
  size_base_larger = nbr_larger/nbr_smaller
  nbr_base_plus1_larger = nbr_larger - nbr_smaller * size_base_larger
  nbr_base_larger = nbr_smaller - nbr_base_plus1_larger
  (char_larger * (size_base_larger+1) + char_smaller) * nbr_base_plus1_larger +
    (char_larger * size_base_larger + char_smaller) * nbr_base_larger
end
```

Note, in Ruby,

```
"1110" * 4
  #=> "1110111011101110"
```

---

```
[[24, 0], [20, 4], [17, 7], [7, 17], [16, 8],
 [11, 13], [5, 19], [2, 22], [1, 23]].each do |nbr1, nbr0|
   puts "nbr 1s = %2d, nbr 0s = %2d: %s" % [nbr1, nbr0, doit(nbr1, nbr0)]
 end
```

displays

```
nbr 1s = 24, nbr 0s =  0: 111111111111111111111111
nbr 1s = 20, nbr 0s =  4: 111110111110111110111110
nbr 1s = 17, nbr 0s =  7: 111011101110110110110110
nbr 1s =  7, nbr 0s = 17: 000100010001001001001001
nbr 1s = 16, nbr 0s =  8: 110110110110110110110110
nbr 1s = 11, nbr 0s = 13: 001001010101010101010101
nbr 1s =  5, nbr 0s = 19: 000010000100001000010001
nbr 1s =  2, nbr 0s = 22: 000000000001000000000001
nbr 1s =  1, nbr 0s = 23: 000000000000000000000001
```